# Security Token Service replacement for the deprecated "Identity and Access Control"

Tags: c#, asp.net, claims-based-identity

I have built and run [Claims-Based-Authorization-89cf736e](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/Claims-Based-Authorization-89cf736e) with VS 2012.  However it will not run with VS 2015. It complains no STS Service.  I am not allowed to use Azure.

Thanks much,
Sam

Answer (score 0):

You can use EmbeddedSts as a replacement to 'Identity and Access Control'.

https://github.com/IdentityModel/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/wiki/EmbeddedSts